# Array em branco - só está removendo a metade deles

Tags: php, array

Tenho o seguinte array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1264-1
            [Quantidade] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1264-3
            [Quantidade] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1264-4
            [Quantidade] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1264-6
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1264-5
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1264-2
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1266-3
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1266-5
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1266-4
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1266-6
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1266-1
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1266-2
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1267-6
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1267-5
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1267-4
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1267-3
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1267-2
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1267-1
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1268-6
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1268-5
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1268-4
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1268-3
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1268-2
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1268-1
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1364-6
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1364-4
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1364-3
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1364-2
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1364-1
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1354-2
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1354-3
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1354-4
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [32] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1354-6
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1354-1
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [34] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1355-2
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [35] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1355-3
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [36] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1355-4
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [37] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1355-6
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [38] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1355-1
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [39] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1356-6
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [40] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1356-4
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [41] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1356-3
            [Quantidade] => 1
        )

    [42] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1356-2
            [Quantidade] => 2
        )

    [43] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1356-1
            [Quantidade] => 3
        )

)
```

Estou fazendo uma verificação para que, quando o índice tiver Quantidade = 0, remova o array.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($arrayMerging); $i++){

    if($arrayMerging[$i]['Quantidade'] == 0){

        unset($arrayMerging[$i]);

    }

}
```

Porém, ele só está removendo do [3] até o [23], por algum motivo que não estou encontrando. Ainda existem arrays do [24] até o [40] para remover, e não remove.

Estou fazendo algo errado?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1264-1
            [Quantidade] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1264-3
            [Quantidade] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1264-4
            [Quantidade] => 3
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1364-6
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1364-4
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1364-3
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1364-2
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1364-1
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1354-2
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1354-3
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1354-4
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [32] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1354-6
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1354-1
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [34] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1355-2
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [35] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1355-3
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [36] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1355-4
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [37] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1355-6
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [38] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1355-1
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [39] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1356-6
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [40] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1356-4
            [Quantidade] => 0
        )

    [41] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1356-3
            [Quantidade] => 1
        )

    [42] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1356-2
            [Quantidade] => 2
        )

    [43] => Array
        (
            [Produto] => ENH1356-1
            [Quantidade] => 3
        )

)
```

Comment: Tem como fornecer a declaração do array para ser facil de reproduzir o problema ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Esta resposta é baseada na **versão 5.4** do PHP

O problema é o construtor de linguagem `unset()`.

Não dá para saber exatamente o motivo, pois o próprio PHP não limita o uso deste construtor no seu manual, mas esse problema acontece quando ele é chamado varias vezes. Faça esse teste:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($arrayMerging); $i++){

    echo $i."</br>";
    if($arrayMerging[$i]['Quantidade'] == 0){

       unset($arrayMerging[$i]);

    }

}
```

Repare que acontece um break no loop justamente no indice 23.

O que você pode fazer é criar um novo array (*isso o php aceita numa boa*), e usar o `unset()` para deletar o antigo:

```
$newArray = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arrayMerging); $i++){
        echo $i."</br>";
        if($arrayMerging[$i]['Quantidade'] !== 0){

            $newArray[] = $arrayMerging[$i];

        }

    }
    unset($arrayMerging);
    print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: Caramba, que loucura. Então esse "bug" no unset() é recorrente? Achei que eu era o problema... hehe. Pensei em fazer dessa maneira também, gerando um novo array, mas queria ver até onde eu havia errado utilizando unset. Obrigado, @Andrei Coelho

Comment: @MaykelEsser sim, é muito estranho. Isso aconteceu comigo a alguns meses atras. Eu inclusive testei em outros servidores e ele acontece da mesma forma. Eu não sei o motivo, pois como eu falei, no manual do php não fala NADA sobre limite de execução desse construtor de linguagem. Além disso, com outros construtores, como o `echo`, isso não acontece. Outra coisa estranha, é que ele não gera nenhum tipo de erro ele apenas sai do `loop`. Se algum dia alguém souber o motivo, poste aqui. Abraço!